# Can a metallic dragon voluntarily revert from Change Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, dragons, shapeshifting

The Monster Manual says that a metallic dragon returns to its true shape when killed.  My question is, can it also return to its own shape when it wants to?

Comment: Are you asking whether it is immune to Polymorph?

Answer (score 17):

**Yes.**

The specific text of the metallic dragons' *Change Shape* action always includes, emphasis mine:

> The dragon magically polymorphs into a humanoid or beast that has a challenge rating no higher than its own, **or back into its true form.** It reverts to its true form if it dies.
>
> ...
>
> In a new form, the dragon retains its alignment, hit points, Hit Dice, ability to speak, proficiencies, Legendary Resistance, lair actions, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores, **as well as this action.**

When the dragon uses *Change Shape*, it retains the ability to use *Change Shape* in the new form; and *Change Shape* can be used to shapeshift back into the dragon's natural form. Since there's no expiry time on the *Change Shape* ability this is normally the only way a dragon can get back to their true form without dying.